# Adding Facebook Pixel Event results in error

Tags: facebook, tracking, event-tracking, facebook-ads-manager, tracking-pixel

I'm trying to create a Facebook Pixel Event, however I get an error on my site, every time I try to add it. The error states: "Request could not be processed: We could not process your request. Please try again." on the page where I want to add the pixel.

The error appears on my website on the subpage where I want to add the event. It's a Facebook Event Manager error, as it seems. This is what it looks like on my page (it's in German though)
[image]

My website is a WordPress website and I added the Pixel via Google Tag Manager. The pixel itself seems to be working fine.

I googled a lot but didn't find anything related to this. The Facebook Pixel Helper Chrome plugin shows that the Pixel is correctly installed and working. When I look at the Chrome developer console I see this error however: "Error: Invalid data".

What could be causing this problem? There is literally NO INFORMATION on this kind of error on the web, so I'm really helpless here.

I cleared all caches, tried using other browsers that I never use but that didn't help either. The weird thing is, it did work only 1 hour ago and now it suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Where is this error coming from? Do you see it on Facebook, or on your own site?   If it is on your own site, there should be more info in your server's error log.  Please edit in additional information from there.       How exactly are you trying to add this pixel, anyway?  Through a tag manager, by editing a text file, through a setting in your content management system?    What CMS are you using?

Comment: As I stated the error shows on the site where I want to add the event. It's a subpage on my WordPress website. There is no error in the server error log, it's an error by the Facebook Event-Manager. I added the Pixel via Google Tag Manager. I added a screenshot of the error, it's in German though.